# How can I draw the output of multiple linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

The data I have is as follows;

```
Oyuncu,OynadigiOyunSayisi,OynadigiDakika,OyunBasinaSayi,NormalAtisSayisi,NormalAtisGirisimi,NormalAtisOrani,3lukSayilar,3lukSayiGirisimi,3lukSayiOrani,SerbestAtisSayisi,SerbestAtisGirisimi,SerbestAtisOrani,HucumRebounduSayisi,DefansRebounduSayisi,ReboundSayisi,AsistSayisi,TopCalma,Blok,TopCalma,Karar
Brandon Ingram,36,27.4,7.4,2.6,7.6,34.7,0.5,2.1,25,1.6,2.3,69.9,0.7,3.4,4.1,1.9,0.4,0.4,1.3,HAYIR
Andrew Harrison,35,26.9,7.2,2,6.7,29.6,0.7,2.8,23.5,2.6,3.4,76.5,0.5,2,2.4,3.7,1.1,0.5,1.6,HAYIR
JaKarr Sampson,74,15.3,5.2,2,4.7,42.2,0.4,1.7,24.4,0.9,1.3,67,0.5,1.7,2.2,1,0.5,0.3,1,HAYIR
Malik Sealy,58,11.6,5.7,2.3,5.5,42.6,0.1,0.5,22.6,0.9,1.3,68.9,1,0.9,1.9,0.8,0.6,0.1,1,EVET
Matt Geiger,48,11.5,4.5,1.6,3,52.4,0,0.1,0,1.3,1.9,67.4,1,1.5,2.5,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,EVET
Tony Bennett,75,11.4,3.7,1.5,3.5,42.3,0.3,1.1,32.5,0.4,0.5,73.2,0.2,0.7,0.8,1.8,0.4,0,0.7,HAYIR
Don MacLean,62,10.9,6.6,2.5,5.8,43.5,0,0.1,50,1.5,1.8,81.1,0.5,1.4,2,0.6,0.2,0.1,0.7,EVET
Tracy Murray,48,10.3,5.7,2.3,5.4,41.5,0.4,1.5,30,0.7,0.8,87.5,0.8,0.9,1.7,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.7,EVET
Duane Cooper,65,9.9,2.4,1,2.4,39.2,0.1,0.5,23.3,0.4,0.5,71.4,0.2,0.6,0.8,2.3,0.3,0,1.1,HAYIR
Dave Johnson,42,8.5,3.7,1.4,3.5,38.3,0.1,0.3,21.4,1,1.4,67.8,0.4,0.7,1.1,0.3,0.2,0,0.7,HAYIR
Corey Williams,35,6.9,2.3,0.9,2.4,36.5,0,0.1,33.3,0.5,0.6,81.8,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.7,0.1,0.1,0.3,HAYIR
......
```

my linear regression code;

```
f = pd.read_csv("NBA5Sene.csv",sep=",")

karar = {"EVET":1,"HAYIR":0}
df.Karar = [karar[item] for item in df.Karar]
x=df.iloc[:,1:-1]
y=df.iloc[:,-1]
x = np.nan_to_num(x)



from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
multiple_lineer_regression = LinearRegression()
multiple_lineer_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)



y_pred = multiple_lineer_regression.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)

b0 = multiple_lineer_regression.intercept
bx=multiple_lineer_regression.coef_

from sklearn import metrics
MSE=metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
RMSE=np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred))
```

I have trained 30 percent of the data in my hand and I want to use the data that I have trained with the remaining 70 percent. I want to draw a chart, how can I do?

Comment: `... how can I do?` - Find a suitable graphing package; read its documentation and/or tutorials; adapt what you learned to your data. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.